# Test about a rows in jComobobox java swing

Tags: java, mysql

I have a combobox where I display data from a table column.

The sql table contains 2 columns: name - etat_syn

So the combobox displays the data of name:

```
    jComboBox3.removeAllItems();
    try{
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etat", "root", "123456"); 
           String sql = "SELECT * FROM pop;";         
           PreparedStatement prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           ResultSet res=prest.executeQuery();
           while(res.next()){ 
                 if(Integer.parseInt(res.getString("etat_syn"))==0){
                       jComboBox3.addItem(res.getString("name")) ;
                 }
           }      
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR :"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

But I want do a test about the index of column "etat_syn" which corresponds to the selected line of column name
I don't know if it's possibe or not

Comment: What do you mean by *index of row* in DB ?

Comment: table have 2 rows in the first they are names like tata-toto and second rows is etat_syn have 0 or 1 i want when i select name from name do a test if the etat_syn coresspended is 0 do a .... else if is 1 do another instructions

Comment: You confuse rows and columns, don't you??

Comment: because i don't know what is in english in french i say colonnes but like we have table of person with 2 columns: name and age

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a bit confusing. You say that you want to do different things based on what the user selected in JComboBox, but all that you are adding is the names of only rows where etat_syn is 0.

```
  if(Integer.parseInt(res.getString("etat_syn"))==0){
                   jComboBox3.addItem(res.getString("name")) ;
  }
```

So in your case, no matter which item you select, the etat_syn value for that item will always be zero.

I think (though I am guessing, you need something like below:

```
while(res.next()){ 
             jComboBox3.addItem(res.getString("name")) ; 
             jComboBox3.setActionCommand(res.getString("etat_syn"));
}
```

and then in the action listener of `jComboBox3`, you can do like this:

```
 jComboBox3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
         String actionCommand = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
         if("0".equals(actionCommand)) {
          //Do this
         } else {
           //Do something else.
         }
       }
 });
```

If you want the processing to be in a action listener of a Button, then you can use a `Map` to store the values, which can then be used for comparision. Your code will change as below:

```
Map<String, Integer> itemsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //Declare this as a member of the class.

while(res.next()){ 
             String name = res.getString("name");
             jComboBox3.addItem() ; 
             int value = Integer.parseInt(res.getString("etat_syn"));
             itemsMap.put(name, value);
}
```

and the action listener of the button will be as below:

```
 yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
         String selectedItem = (String)jComboBox3.getSelectedItem();
         int value = itemsMap.get(selectedItem);
         if(value == 0) {
          //Do this
         } else {
           //Do something else.
         }
       }
  });
```

Comment: Yes that i want the last that you sent while(res.next()){ 
            jComboBox3.addItem(res.getString("name")) ; 
             jComboBox3.setActionCommand(res.getString("etat_syn"));
    }
    if(jComboBox3.getSelectedItem() != null){
    String actionCommand = jComboBox3.getActionCommand();
 if("0".equals(actionCommand)) {
     System.out.print("Etat_down");
 } else {
System.out.print("Etat_Up");
 }
    } i do that to when i select item from combobox automaticly do a test and display the result without doing a button but i have in result the first system.out.print he dosen't do a test

Comment: Okey i do it with botton but the result is always Down means he don't take the getActionCOmmand

Comment: if(jComboBox3.getSelectedItem()!=null){
        
    if(Integer.parseInt(jComboBox3.getActionCommand())==0){
System.out.print("Down");
   
    }else
    {
System.out.print("Up");
   
    }
    
        }

Comment: if(jComboBox3.getSelectedItem()!=null){
            String name=jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etat", "root", "123456"); 
         String sql = "SELECT etat_syn FROM pop where name='"+name+"'";              
            PreparedStatement prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet res=prest.executeQuery();
                String etat=res.getString("etat_syn");            
                System.out.print("etat : "+etat);

Comment: but it gives me this error: ERROR :Before start of result set